# How to get coordinates of external application opened by Java program

Tags: java, windows, screenshot

Using Java program I am opening an external application( for example: notepad). How can i get coordinates/location of external application for screen capture/screen-shots.

I can take screen-shots of the whole window, but not for a particular application.

I have already tried "Robot" for screen capturing but not able to capture a particular area as I am not able to find the location and size of the application window.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AppCheck {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("***********************");
      try {

          System.out.println("Opening notepad");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("notepad");
            try {
                int count=0;
                while(process.isAlive())
                {
                    System.out.println("process name : " + process.getClass().getName());
                    Field f = process.getClass().getDeclaredField("handle");
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    long handl = f.getLong(process);
                    System.out.println("Process ID : " + handl);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Closing notepad");
            process.destroy();          

      } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
      }
      System.out.println("************************************");
   }
}
```